# Stripe Payment Direct vs Destination Charges

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am trying to build e-commerce platform for my project. Sellers can upload their products and customers can purchase them. Payment gateway I chose is Stripe, but there are some types of charges that I am confused about. Can you guys correct me that I understood the payment flow right?

**Direct charge**

Buyer buys product -> stripe charges buyer -> stripe pays seller

**Destination charge**

Buyer buys product -> money comes in to my stripe account -> I payout money to seller

I am confused at this part. If I use direct charge, Stripe handles charges so it does have nothing to do with mu stripe account except for application fee?

Lastly, if I were to build an e-commerce platform that has many sellers, which charge is suitable? And which account type is suitable?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The charge type you use with Stripe Connect (direct or destination) mostly depends on the type of connected accounts you want to use:

- Direct charges should be used with [Standard](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts) accounts
- Destination charges should be used with [Express](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts) and/or [Custom](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts) accounts

In order to determine which account type is the best choice for you use case check out the ["Choose your account type"](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts) documentation.

Once you've decided on an account type you should read either [the documentation for direct charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges) or [the documentation for destination charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges).

Your description of "an e-commerce platform that has many sellers" is too vague to give you a specific recommendation, but reading through the documentation above should make the choice clear.